# Kubernetes : RabbitMQ pod is spammed with connections from kube-system

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, keda

I'm currently learning Kubernetes and all its quircks.
I'm currently using a rabbitMQ Deployment, service and pod in my cluster to exchange messages between apps in the cluster. However, I saw an abnormal amount of the rabbitMQ pod restarts.
After installing prometheus and Grafana to see the problem, I saw that the rabbitMQ pod would consume more and more memory and cpu until it gets killed by the OOMkiller every two hours or so. The graph looks like this :

[Graph of CPU consumption in my cluster (rabbitmq in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgAM.png)

After that I looked into the rabbitMQ pod UI, and saw that an app in my cluster (ip 10.224.0.5) was constantly creating new connections, this IP corresponding to my kube-system and my prometheus instance, as shown by the following logs :

```
k get all -A -o wide | grep 10.224.0.5
E1223 12:13:48.231908   23198 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Got empty response for: external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
E1223 12:13:48.311831   23198 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Got empty response for: external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
kube-system          pod/azure-ip-masq-agent-xh9jk                                1/1     Running   0             25d     10.224.0.5    aks-agentpool-37892177-vmss000001   <none>           <none>
kube-system          pod/cloud-node-manager-h5ff5                                 1/1     Running   0             25d     10.224.0.5    aks-agentpool-37892177-vmss000001   <none>           <none>
kube-system          pod/csi-azuredisk-node-sf8sn                                 3/3     Running   0             3d15h   10.224.0.5    aks-agentpool-37892177-vmss000001   <none>           <none>
kube-system          pod/csi-azurefile-node-97nbt                                 3/3     Running   0             19d     10.224.0.5    aks-agentpool-37892177-vmss000001   <none>           <none>
kube-system          pod/kube-proxy-2s5tn                                         1/1     Running   0             3d15h   10.224.0.5    aks-agentpool-37892177-vmss000001   <none>           <none>
monitoring           pod/prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-dztwx                1/1     Running   0             20h     10.224.0.5    aks-agentpool-37892177-vmss000001   <none>           <none>
```

Also, I noticed that these connections seem tpo be blocked by rabbitMQ, as the field connection.blocked in the client properties is set to true, as shown in the follwing image:

[Print screen of a connection details from rabbitMQ pod's UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9JaB.png)

I saw in the documentation that rabbitMQ starts to blocks connections when it hits low on resources, but I set the cpu and memory limits to 1 cpu and 1 Gib RAM, and the connections are blocked from the start anyway.

On the cluster, I'm also using Keda which uses the rabbitmq pod, and polls it every one second to see if there are any messages in a queue (I set pollingInterval to 1 in the yaml). But as I said earlier, it's not Keda that's creating all the connections, it's kube-system. Unless keda uses a component described earlier in the log to poll rabbitmq, and that the Keda's polling interval does not corresponds to seconds (which is highly unlikely as it's written in the docs that this polling intertval is given in seconds), I don't know at all what's going on with all these connections.

The following section contains the yamls of all the components that might be involved with this problem (keda and rabbitmq) :

```
rabbitMQ Replica Count.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    component: rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: taskQueue
        component: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rabbitmq:3.11.5-management
        name: rabbitmq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: http
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 1Gi
```

```
rabbitMQ Service.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    component: rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
    name: amqp
  - port: 15672
    targetPort: 15672
    name: http
  selector:
    app: taskQueue
    component: rabbitmq
```

```
keda JobScaler, Secret and TriggerAuthentication (sample data is just a replacement for fields that I do not want to be revealed :) ):

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
data:
  host: sample-host  # base64 encoded value of format amqp://guest:password@localhost:5672/vhost
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-trigger-auth-rabbitmq-conn
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: host
      name: keda-rabbitmq-secret
      key: host
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
metadata:
  name: builder-job-scaler
  namespace: default
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    parallelism: 1
    completions: 1
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 600
    backoffLimit: 5
    template:
      spec:
        volumes:
        - name: shared-storage
          emptyDir: {}
        initContainers:
        - name: sourcesfetcher
          image: sample image
          volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-storage
            mountPath: /mnt/shared
          env:
          - name: SHARED_STORAGE_MOUNT_POINT
            value: /mnt/shared
          - name: RABBITMQ_ENDPOINT
            value: sample host
          - name: RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME
            value: buildOrders
        containers:
        - name: builder
          image: sample image
          volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-storage
            mountPath: /mnt/shared
          env:
          - name: SHARED_STORAGE_MOUNT_POINT
            value: /mnt/shared
          - name: MINIO_ENDPOINT
            value: sample endpoint
          - name: MINIO_PORT 
            value: sample port
          - name: MINIO_USESSL  
            value: "false"
          - name: MINIO_ROOT_USER
            value: sample user
          - name: MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: sampel password
          - name: BUCKET_NAME 
            value: "hex"
          - name: SERVER_NAME
            value: sample url
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 512Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 512Mi
        restartPolicy: OnFailure
  pollingInterval: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 2
  minReplicaCount: 0
  rollout:
    strategy: gradual

  triggers:
  - type: rabbitmq
    metadata:
      protocol: amqp
      queueName: buildOrders
      mode: QueueLength
      value: "1"
    authenticationRef:
      name: keda-trigger-auth-rabbitmq-conn
```

Any help would very much appreciated!